# Python Path Not Read Correctly in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

When trying to create a filepath in Python with Selenium to run.

I tried running the code line by lane and for this code:

```
path = os.path.expanduser("~\Anaconda2\selenium\webdriver\firefox\amd64\geckodriver.exe")
```

In the variable explorer it shows as below:

```
C:\Users\username\Anaconda2\selenium\webdriverirefox(bullet character)md64\geckodriver.exe
```

Thus running into an error `[Error 267] The directory name is invalid`.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape (`\`) your backslashes, or put an `r` before your string, which `string2` below demonstrates.

```
>>> string1 = "~\Anaconda2\selenium\webdriver\firefox\amd64\geckodriver.exe"
>>> string1
'~\\Anaconda2\\selenium\\webdriver\x0cirefox\x07md64\\geckodriver.exe'

>>> string2 = r"~\Anaconda2\selenium\webdriver\firefox\amd64\geckodriver.exe"
>>> string2
'~\\Anaconda2\\selenium\\webdriver\\firefox\\amd64\\geckodriver.exe'
```